# want to add timer and slide out

Tags: css, css-transitions

want but time after slide in this img , want to hold 10sec after that slide ou same side when in , am try more but cant solution

```
**CSS:**

<div>
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 536px;
    height: 96px;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    right: -536px;
    width: 536px;
    height: 96px;
    -webkit-animation: slide 0.5s backwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    animation: slide 2.8s forwards;
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
   100% { right: 0; }
}

@keyframes slide {
   100% { right: 0; }
}
```

this is html

```
HTML:
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="slide" src="https://c.top4top.net/p_1186khyzu1.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

i hope it will help you :
Use `css keyframe percentage`

```css
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 536px;
    height: 96px;
}

#slide {
    position: absolute;
    right: -536px;
    width: 536px;
    height: 96px;
    animation: slide 14s forwards;
}



@keyframes slide {
    15% {right:0}
    85% {right:0}
   100% { right: -536; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="slide" src="https://c.top4top.net/p_1186khyzu1.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: is so fast in start , want to more slowly and after start is hold or stop 10sec 
after that slide out same animation :)

Comment: you so famous , thank you so so much , can you tell me how to edit when want more time , example : 

want strat every : 1m = 60s , Repetition
After that hold or stop : 10s
After that Slide out

Comment: this is so good , but this hold 10s , can edit timer or not ?

Answer (score 0):

`-webkit-animation` and `animation` is essentially the same property except `-webkit-` was experimental support in older versions.

You cannot use `-webkit-animation` to specify a different animation and since they are the same thing, the `animation` style is taking priority in this case as it's defined later than `-webkit-animation`.

Instead of doing separate animations, you need to think of doing this in 1 animation.

1. Wait 2 seconds (`animation: 2s`)
2. Slide in in 2.8 seconds
3. Hold for 10 seconds
4. Slide out in 0.5 seconds

Total animation duration: 13.3 seconds

- `2.8 / 13.3 = 21%`
- `10 / 13.3 = 75%`
- `0.5 / 13.3 = 3.7%`

*I round the percentage off to number that's easier to manage in this example.*

So, you want to first set about `20%` to have the slider to be fully shown (`right: 0`), then you want to keep it there for about another `75%` (`20% + 75% = 95%`) of the duration by keeping it at (`right: 0`). Finally, you want to slide it out by setting `right` back to what it was with `inherit`.

In the end, you want your `slide` animation to last for 13.3s.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 536px;
  height: 96px;
}

#slide {
  position: absolute;
  right: -536px;
  width: 536px;
  height: 96px;
  animation: slide 13.3s forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  20% { right: 0; }
  95% { right: 0; }
  100% { right: inherit; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img id="slide" src="https://via.placeholder.com/536x96" />
</div>
```

Comment: you code is good but want after slide in , wait 10sec after that slide out

Comment: @Majed I have edited my answer according to what you want.